# Using preseed, how do I select the HWE kernel?

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, kernel, preseed

We have a working fully automated install of 16.04 using preseed. I need to add the HWE kernel. Is there a `d-i ???` option to select the HWE kernel? If not, what is the usual approach to use an HWE kernel on install? My current best guess is to use a late_command tweak but that seems... dangerous at best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options,

If the machine will boot with the earlier kernel this will work.

`d-i pkgsel/include` will work, and should exist in your config, appending `linux-generic-hwe-16.04` will boot to the hwe kernel once the install is complete.

Or you can this line:

```
d-i base-installer/kernel/override-image string linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

After this line:

```
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap
```

The second option is preferable in my experience.